# Classnotfound exception while running hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop.

I have a file Wordcount.java which refers hadoop.jar and stanford-parser.jar

I am running the following commnad

```
javac -classpath .:hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:stanford-parser.jar -d ep WordCount.java 

jar cvf ep.jar -C ep .

bin/hadoop jar ep.jar WordCount gutenburg gutenburg1
```

After executing i am getting the following error:

```
lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
```

The class is in stanford-parser.jar ...

What can be the possible problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the standford-parser jar when invoking hadoop also, not just the compiler. (If you look in ep.jar, I imagine it will only have one file in it - WordCount.class)

E.g.

```
bin/hadoop jar ep.jar WordCount -libjars stanford-parser.jar gutenburg gutenburg1
```

[See Map/Reduce Tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)

Comment: Hi, I tried the command you suggested but i am getting this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -libjars

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with libjars in the correct place. Please try again!

Comment: I tried the command you posted, am getting this error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:11111/user/hadoop/-libjars

Comment: adding -libjars after the classname only makes it the first arg sent to the class, it's useless

Answer (score 1):

mdma is on the right track, but you'll also need your job driver to implement Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I think the reason -libjars option doesn't get recognized by your program is because you are not parsing it by calling GenericOptionsParser.getRemainingArgs().  In Hadoop 0.21.0's WordCount.java example (in mapred/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/), this pieces of code is found, and after doing the same in my program, -libjars *comma-separated-jars* is recognized:

```
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
  System.exit(2);
}

...
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that you can simply edit $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh and add your JARs to HADOOP_CLASSPATH.
This is probably simplest and most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can try since the -libjars doesn't seem to be working for you is to package everything into a single jar, ie your code + the dependencies into a single jar.

This was how it had to be done prior to ~Hadoop-0.18.0 (somewhere around there they *fixed* this).

Using ant (i use ant in eclipse) you can set up a build that unpacks the dependencies and adds them to the target build project. You can probably hack this yourself though, by manually unpacking the dependency jar and adding the contents to your jar.

Even though I use 0.20.1 now I still use this method. It makes starting a job form the command-line simpler.